# How to check whether TextFormField is focused or not

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField with focusNode:

```
TextFormField(
   key: Key('login-username-field-key'),
   controller: loginTextController,
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   onFieldSubmitted: (term){
      _changeFocusField(context, _loginFocus, _passwordFocus);
   },
   focusNode: _loginFocus,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context).loginFieldUsername
   ),
),
```

And then:

```
// Check that text field initially is not focused
final TextFormField textField = tester.widget(find.byKey(Key('login-username-field-key')));
expect(textField.focusNode.hasFocus, isFalse);
```

But from the docs I saw that [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) doesn't have 'focusNode' property (like [TextField.focusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/focusNode.html).hasFocus).

So how to check that behavior?

PS I mean we can use FocusNode listeners, but I don't want to do that just for testing purposes. It should be really simply field.focusNode like for TextField.

Comment: I think the only way by using ``addListener``

Comment: The docs say: "This is a convenience widget that wraps a TextField widget in a FormField." Perhaps you need to do it yourself if you need the focusNode.

Answer (score 2):

You should add listener, where you can check state of your textFormField.
The method `hasFocus` return true or false.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loginFocus.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  void _onFocusChange(){
    debugPrint("Focus: "+_focus.hasFocus.toString());
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet might solve the issue and provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please consider an [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.